# Igbt for AC 32A switch

Tags: switches, ac, igbt

I have been around this forum, and I am not sure I found my answer. I would like to realize a small and cheap AC switch. Relays being too big, I got interested in IGBT.

The goal is to turn on and off a standard 220Vrms AC with a maximum load of 32A. I figured out that IGBT could be a good alternative because of their high voltage/current performances. As speed is not a constraint here, it seems to be better than Mosfet.

Here is what I image I could do:
[image]
There is no isolation in the 5V generator as no one is supposed to acces it (wireless control).

I would like to know if my circuit above is correct, and what would be the characteristics required for the IGBT to handle 220Vac 32A. For example, I had a look to this one: http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=TIG065E8
I feel it is a little too small to handle this job... but I can't see any solid reason in the datasheet showing that it cannot.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good circuit idea, but I think that will be neither cheap nor small. 
For each IGBT you'll pay around 1 USD + 1 USD for each 600V diode (D1, D2). So ~ 4USD for the power parts is pretty expensive.

I would have a look for a Triac 16A D2PAK (~40USDcent) and a opto triac (~20USDcent) for driving it from a controller. I'm not sure about the 32Amps because normal household fuses are limited to 16 Amps. But with a TOP3 Triac 40 Amps with proper cooling is also possible.

Any way, the proposed circuit should work. I did a simulation in LTSpice and driving the IGBT should be possible. I've found an IGBT simulation model [here](http://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/235175).

But I think the gate drive circuit won't be easy to create with-out opto isolation because for Q1 you have to apply 12V against GND (or load) (that's easy) but for Q2 you'll need 12V against Line voltage.

I haven't found a way for driving. In the simple simulation that is working I have used two independend voltage sources to create the drive voltage.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll have a look to the triac. And also to an LTspice simulation. Thank you for the model this would have been my next question.

Comment: By the way, should the Igbts I found (Onsemi) would do the job? I may try this circuit. Thank you again

Comment: I would look for a 600V trench IGBT (like one of [these]( http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?FV=fff40015%2Cfff8007e%2Ccb00033%2Ccb00039%2Ccb0003b%2Ccb00040%2Ccb0005b%2Ccb00068%2Ccb00076%2Ccb00077%2Ccb00078%2Ccb00079%2Ccb0007a%2Ccb0007b%2Ccb0007c%2Ccb0007d%2Ccb0007e%2Ccb0007f%2Ccb00080%2Ccb0008d%2Ccb0008f%2Ccb00093%2Ccb000ab%2Ccb000ac%2Ccb000f1%2Ccb001a1%2Ccb001ce&k=igbt+600v&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=0&pbfree=0&rohs=0&quantity=&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) because a 400 V type is too close to the AC peak voltage and may blow easily.Maybe OV protection is required